# Using sed to match exact variable

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am using a shell script which utilizes sed to find and replace one variable with another variable. In the script, I have set variables as unique directories:

```
"sub1=$INPUTPATH\sub1.nii.gz"
...
"sub53=$INPUTPATH\sub53.nii.gz"
```

The shell script then calls upon a template (designed to be used in another program) where all instances of a particular variable (i.e., placeholder label) are replaced with a specified variable. For example:

```
for i in $TEMPLATE; do
sed -e 's@OUTPUT@'$OUTPUT'@g'\
 -e 's@sub1@'$sub1'@g'\
 -e 's@sub2@'$sub2'@g'\
...
 -e 's@sub53@'$sub53'@g'\
```

This code appears to work satisfactorily until I reach double digits, where as an example, "sub1" replaces "sub10", "sub11", "sub12", etc, and adds the second digit to the end of the specified path.

```
sub10=$INPUTPATH\sub1.nii.gz0
sub11=$INPUTPATH\sub1.nii.gz1
sub12=$INPUTPATH\sub1.nii.gz2
```

I believe this error is due to the code not specifying an "exact match". I have tried iterations to correct this to no avail (e.g., [sed replace exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850806/sed-replace-exact-match)). Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: A trivial fix would be to reorder your substitutions such that `sub10` is performed before `sub1`.

Comment: Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your patterns. `\b`, `\<`, and `\>`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much! Using the \b appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner)'s [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418819/using-sed-to-match-exact-variable#comment50810676_31418819) solved my issue! Example syntax as follows:

```
 -e 's@\bsub1\b@'$sub1'@g'\
 -e 's@\bsub2\b@'$sub2'@g'\
 -e 's@\bsub3\b@'$sub3'@g'\
```